# Physical Bluetooth Keyboard is not able to access to chats (Whatsapp, Telegram) in Android 10

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, bluetooth, external-keyboard

I have a very strange situation that I have not found yet something in the internet that could lead me to solve this issue.

I paired my physical bluetooth keyboard (**Keychron K2**) with my phone (**Huawei P30 Lite with Android EMUI Version 10.0.0** which I think is Android 10) and I have found the way to control almost everything, but when I access to a chat application like WhatsApp, I am able to select the available chats in the application but when I type Enter to go into selected chat, it does not go to that chat, it highlights the chat like it was selected but not with the intention to go into it...

If I leave the enter pressed, this will show me available options/actions that I could use with that specific chat like delete the conversation, pin message, etc. This behavior occurs also with Telegram.

Is there any body with some hints regarding how I could be able to access to an specific chat selected to start chatting with my keyboard without having to use the native touchscreen control to start using the application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible with a physical keyboard yet. I tried every key and many combinations too.. failed..
Then i tried remapping the key(one and only relevant function available is select/enter which does not work for selecting chats).. failed again..
I downloaded a physical keyboard helper(nothing helpful in it).. it failed too..

I think you'll have to tap the chats on the phone everytime you want to open any from the app.. OR you can create chat shortcuts on homescreen but that will be too weary adding every contact and messing up your homescreen.

**An efficient solution will be to use a cursor (controlled from keyboard)**

Comment: a cursor would not be nearly enough, because many things happen on android through gestures. ideal solution would probably be some way to trigger a list of possible actions on current screen, and pick one. including moving the screen around, which could be the most complicated one (to accelerate scrolling, for instance). at least we would have the END button as an advantage. :D but there's currently a couple of good enough solutions i'm using... i'll post an answer.

Comment: @cregox I admire your effort. But the keyboard does the rest job done except opening the chats.. So in my opinion a cursor would be enough to just open the chat. This will be the most simple solution to this i guess

Answer (score 0):

you can use key mapper app (free and open source) to map a bunch of functions, including tapping the screen.

or you can get termux and do everything from CLI. (warning: might be a huge learning curve ahead)

both options are very tech-savy, in exponential quantities, but they mostly work for your case (and mine, i use both).

as i said on the other comment, still looking for the ideal solution (that should be possible) of getting a list of every possible action on screen after pressing some trigger button. something a bit like ctrl+alt+m on termux.

sadly, almost every single app are really not made to work well with keyboard, but luckily a lot of them are simple enough that they do work anyway (like delta chat).